# How to configure AWS Beanstalk autoscaling on latency metrics with zero minimum instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want all the instances to terminate if no request is received within a period of time (.e.g 1 hour) and then start an instance or another instance if average latency goes to 500ms or there is no instance. How can I do that? It seems that when the minimum instance number is zero and the current instances were shutdown (i.e. due inactivity) beanstalk refuses to spin new instances.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic beanstalk does not support 0 instance configuration.
It also makes no sense to only scale up the environment when the request comes in since scaling takes a few minutes at best, and by that time the request will time out.

So in a nutshell - Elastic beanstalk is not the solution for your problem. Mesosphere can accommodate for such a need but again, it is not a good practice to completely deny service as long as no requests come in.

Comment: I think it's rather a lack of better automation than good or bad practice.  Google Appengine provides a such service and it works quite fast(i.e. just a few seconds delay for the first request). I think the main reason why AWS is so slow is because they start virtual machines instead of containers. And even with that slow start-up time I still believe it makes sense to support 0 instance configuration for a development mode.

Comment: Ah, for dev your solution makes more sense, naturally. However - there is still a major difference between spinning up an instance and a container. If google is offereing that service I suspect it's a matter of time before AWS will come up with their own competitive one, but for now I do not know of anything that can accomplish that on their platform.